# Setting up Phragile with Phabricator

Tags: php, phabricator, wikimedia

I am trying to setup Phragile with Phabricator. I did the steps mentioned in [https://github.com/wmde/phragile] But I don't understand if Phragile is hosted separately or it is already a part of Phabricator. If it is separate, how do I set up its URL and what other things I need to do to have it up and running, including features like creating projects/sprints as mentioned in the feature page?

Answer (score 1):

Phragile looks like hosted separately but using phabricator OAuth server (to enable/config). I think the communication is done from Phragile -> Phabricator and not really the opposite. Phragile needs to know where phabricator is, this is configured in the `.env` file.

If your are looking for a Phabricator app I can recommend the one made by the WikiMedia foundation here: https://github.com/wikimedia/phabricator-extensions-Sprint